# biblatex citation styles

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the `biblatex-chicago` package to get my references in the author-year format, but I'm struggling with the citation styles. I'm using `\autocite{cite key}` modified using `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}` to be able to have a citation in parenthesis after providing a data figure  (e.g. "increased by 5% (UNESCO, 2012)"). But I would also like to use `\textcite{cite key}` to cite a paper in the fashion 'according to Nash (1950)".  Instead, I'm getting 'according to Nash1950" (the cite key in bold letters).

Is `\textcite` not compatible with `biblatex-chicago`? This citation style is supposed to look like Nash (1950). I've tried removing `-chicago` and running again, or using the `harvard` style. I also found a bibliography style (a .bst file) specific to the economics field that is a customized way to achieve citations in the format Nash (1950) so I tried using `\bibliographystyle{econ_aer.bst}` but that didn't work either.

Please help

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{UNESCO2001,
  author = {UNESCO.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}

@misc{Nash1950,
  author = {Nash, D.},
  year = {1950},
  title = {Game Theory},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

According to \textcite{Nash1950}. data figure \autocite{UNESCO2001}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate]{biblatex-chicago}` or `\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,natbib]{biblatex-chicago}`?

Comment: If you are getting **Nash1950** (in bold) in this example file, it sounds like you are not running the usual sequence of `latex`, `biber`, `latex` (or `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex` depending on which `backend` option you use).

Comment: Looks like adding natbib following Kurt's suggestion above did the trick. I appreciate the help!!

Comment: I voted on your answer, but I'm not seeing a green checkmark next to it... ?... I read the "How do you accept an answer?" doc. Sorry if I'm not doing it right.

Answer (score 7):

To get a author-year format just add option `authordate` to the call of package `biblatex-chicago`.  If you need some (not all!) functions used in package `natbib` add the option `natbib` to the call of `biblatex-chicago`. Do **not** use option `natbib=true` (see manual, page 3 for explanation)! You can't use package `natbib` and `biblatex-chicago` together.

More informations to [biblatex-chicago](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago) you will find in the package documentation.

With the following MWE (with a little bit pretty printing) you should get what you want:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{UNESCO2001,
  author = {UNESCO},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {Alpha},
}
@misc{Nash1950,
  author = {Nash, D.},
  year   = {1950},
  title  = {Game Theory},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber
 ,authordate     % returns Nash (1950)
%,natbib         % make some functions of package natbib available
]{biblatex-chicago} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

According to \textcite{Nash1950}. data figure \autocite{UNESCO2001}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This will gave you the result:

[image]